# can I select an html element created by setting the inner html of another element?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating new elements by setting the inner html of the container to this:

```
function render() {
library.innerHTML = "";
for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
    if(myLibrary[i].read){
    library.innerHTML += 
    '<div class="book__container">' +
    '<div class="book">' +
        '<div class="title__content">' +
            '<span class="main">Title : </span><span class="book__title">' +` ${myLibrary[i].title}`+'</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="author__content">' +
            '<span class="main">Author : </span><span class="book__author">'+` ${myLibrary[i].author}`+'</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="pages__content">' +
            '<span class="main">Pages : </span><span class="book__pages">'+` ${myLibrary[i].pages}`+'</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="book__read-elements">' +
            '<span class="book__read yes" style="color:rgb(110, 176, 120)">I read it</span>' +
            '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>' +
            '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-times"></i>' +
            '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
'</div>';
   
}else {
library.innerHTML += 
    '<div class="book__container">' +
    '<div class="book">' +
        '<div class="title__content">' +
            '<span class="main">Title : </span><span class="book__title">' +` ${myLibrary[i].title}`+'</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="author__content">' +
            '<span class="main">Author : </span><span class="book__author">'+` ${myLibrary[i].author}`+'</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="pages__content">' +
            '<span class="main">Pages : </span><span class="book__pages">'+` ${myLibrary[i].pages}`+'</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="book__read-elements">' +
            '<span class="book__read no" style="color:rgb(194, 89, 89)"">I have not read it</span>' +
            '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>' +
            '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-times"></i>' +
            '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
'</div>';

}
```

Is there a way to select the i elements and add event listeners to them? I've tried but it says the elements are null

Comment: `library.querySelector('i')` would return all `i` tags in the library.  You can perform querySelector and querySelectorAll against `library` as any normal DOM Element

Comment: You have to wait till the elements Loads on the DOM it means you have to wait for them, once the elements are created you can select them.

Comment: because you didn't show what `library` element is, it is not possible to respond on your question

Comment: @Carlos1232 you can select elements within an element, so long as you have a reference to it.  It does not have to be attached to the DOM.  It is essentially a dom fragment.

Comment: Example: `var fragment = document.createElement('div');  fragment.innerHTML = '<span><i>Can I be selected without being attached to the DOM?</i></span>'; console.log(fragment.querySelector('i'));`

Answer (score 1):

The key is to run your function that selects the i items after the insertion is finished

One way to do that is by using a `callback`

To understand the callbacks check this link: https://javascript.info/callbacks

```js
const library = document.querySelector(".lib")

myLibrary = [
{ "title": "cool", "author":"cooler", "pages":"the-coolest"},
{ "title": "cool-1", "author":"cooler-1", "pages":"the-coolest-1"},
{ "title": "cool-2", "author":"cooler-2", "pages":"the-coolest-2"}
]

function render(callback) {
library.innerHTML = "";
for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
    if(myLibrary[i].read){
    library.innerHTML += 
    '<div class="book__container">' +
    '<div class="book">' +
        '<div class="title__content">' +
            '<span class="main">Title : </span><span class="book__title">' +` ${myLibrary[i].title}`+'</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="author__content">' +
            '<span class="main">Author : </span><span class="book__author">'+` ${myLibrary[i].author}`+'</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="pages__content">' +
            '<span class="main">Pages : </span><span class="book__pages">'+` ${myLibrary[i].pages}`+'</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="book__read-elements">' +
            '<span class="book__read yes" style="color:rgb(110, 176, 120)">I read it</span>' +
            '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>' +
            '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-times"></i>' +
            '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
'</div>';
   
} else {
library.innerHTML += 
    '<div class="book__container">' +
    '<div class="book">' +
        '<div class="title__content">' +
            '<span class="main">Title : </span><span class="book__title">' +` ${myLibrary[i].title}`+'</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="author__content">' +
            '<span class="main">Author : </span><span class="book__author">'+` ${myLibrary[i].author}`+'</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="pages__content">' +
            '<span class="main">Pages : </span><span class="book__pages">'+` ${myLibrary[i].pages}`+'</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="book__read-elements">' +
            '<span class="book__read no" style="color:rgb(194, 89, 89)"">I have not read it</span>' +
            '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>' +
            '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-times"></i>' +
            '<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
'</div>';

}
}

callback()
}

function addListeners () {
  const items = document.querySelectorAll("i")
  items.forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item)
    item.addEventListener("click", function () {})
  })
}

render(addListeners)
```

```html
<div class="lib"></div>
```